# Tied optionality of regex groups without duplicating the obligatory pattern part

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a regex like `"(?<opening>\[)?(?<body>\w+)(?<closing>\])?"`.
This is in .NET.
Currently both opening and closing are optional and independent.
So the question is: is it possible to make the `closing` match only if `opening` was encountered, otherwise treat as a mismatch?

Currently it matches all of possible variants: `body`, `[body`, `body]`, `[body]`.
But my aim is to match either `body` or `[body]`

*P.S. I know it's possible via `((?<opening>\[)(?<body>\w+)(?<closing>\])|(?<body>\w+))`,

but my actual `<body>` pattern is quite big and complicated to duplicate it like that.*

Comment: Is it in PHP or .NET? What is your regex flavor?

Comment: Note there might be no way to do it if your body pattern is much more complex than that. It also depends on the regex flavor. With PCRE, `(?:(?<o>\[)|(?<!\[))\b(?<body>\w++)(?(o)(?<c>])|(?!]))` [could work](https://regex101.com/r/PeY4MN/2/) for the current "toy" example.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the current scenario, you can use

```cs
(?:(?<o>\[)|(?<!\[))\b(?<body>\w+)(?(o)(?<c>])|(?![]\w]))
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3Co%3E%5C%5B%29%7C%28%3F%3C!%5C%5B%29%29%5Cb%28%3F%3Cbody%3E%5Cw%2B%29%28%3F%28o%29%28%3F%3Cc%3E%5D%29%7C%28%3F!%5B%5D%5Cw%5D%29%29&i=body%2C%20%5Bbody%2C%20body%5D%2C%20%5Bbody%5D.%0D%0A%20body%20%5Bbody%5D). *Details*:

- `(?:(?<o>\[)|(?<!\[))`
- `\b` - a word boundary (it works here since the next pattern part matches a word char)
- `(?<body>\w+)` - Group "body": one or more word chars
- `(?(o)(?<c>])|(?![]\w]))` -  a conditional construct that, if Group "o" stack is not empty,

  - `(?<c>])` matches and captures into Group "c" a `]` char,
  - `|` - or else (if Group "o" did not match)
  - `(?![]\w])` - requires that there is no `]` and a word char immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: I've adjusted it just a bit due to my particular needs and it works just as I wanted. Thank you!